# Eclim executing first save of code

Tags: vim, eclim

I'm having a bit of trouble with eclim. Everything works perfectly fine but when I try `:Java`, it does not run the current state that my code is in.
The first time I ran my code it was a simple hello world program to check if eclim was working. Now it should produce a window and render some color but if I run it with eclim all it does is print "Hello World" to the console. If I exit vim and compile/run it from the terminal it opens the window and renders the colors. So I know the program is working but eclim will still only run the first save that I did of it and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building your project using the `:ProjectBuild` command before running your code with `:Java`?